# function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

okay, I'm reusing this function throughout my app, and react es lint is giving a warning that there is an unsafe variable.

```
function scrollHorizontally(e,listOfBannedClasses, parentClass)
    {
    /*
    e: event, listOfBannedClasses:array of classNames, parentClass:  target className
    */
    let target = e.target;
    let returnEarly = false;
    listOfBannedClasses.forEach(c=>{
        if(target.classList.contains(c)){returnEarly=true;}
    })
        if(returnEarly){return} //if you are hovering over one of these divs default scroll behavior
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    while(target.parentNode!== undefined && target.className!==parentClass){
        if(listOfBannedClasses.some(x=>target.parentNode.classList.contains(x)))
            {
            return;
        }      
        target = target.parentNode; //'unsafe' reference
    }
    let deltaY = e.deltaY ;
    target.scrollLeft -= (-deltaY|| e.wheelData || -e.detail);  
}
```

I've been staring at the code for a while now. and I'm blanking on a different way of writing it to not have target=target.parentNode in there.

the code works, it takes a scroll event, an array of classNames, and a target - and will only scroll left or right if the DOM walk hits none banned classes and eventually reaches the target class.
the result is you can scroll up/down lists, and left/right on containers of those lists.

Comment: `.parentNode` won't be `undefined`. It's either a `Node` or `null`, hence `target = target.parentNode` can throw a `TypeError`

Comment: aye, thanks for that catch! -that's something easily fixed :) still working on reworking the function.